# Change UIDocumentInteractionController Icons

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I was wondering how I can change the icons that show up in the table view.

I looked at the documentation for `UIDocumentInteractionController` on **apple.com** but I didn't have any success editing my plist. If someone knows how to do this please help.

Thank you
[image: UITableView Icons]

Answer (score 0):

[Registering the File Types Your App Supports](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/RegisteringtheFileTypesYourAppSupports.html) describes how to register custom file types together with their icons in an app.

So if you use "com.example.myformat" as UTI type in the *LSItemContentTypes* array of the plist, and set the `UTI` property of the document interaction controller to the same string "com.example.myformat", then your icon should be used.

Comment: Thank you for the reply i am going to try this but what would be the com.example.myformat for lets say a simple .png file?

Comment: Hi I've just tried everything such as editing .plist values but i cannot seem to change these icons if someone has so this please comment. Thank you

Comment: @CristianRivera: Perhaps I misunderstood your question. Do you want to display icons for file types which are unknown to the system? Or do you want to display a different icon for standard file types like JPEG or PNG?