# Change UIDocument Interaction Icons

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uidocumentinteraction

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change UIDocumentInteractionController Icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11912401/change-uidocumentinteractioncontroller-icons)

I currently have a UITableView in my app that uses the UIDocumentInteractionController to show a default image for a certain file type: [image]

I was wondering if i have a place holder lets say for any image file type can i have that show instead of the default one? This is what i would like the default image placeholder to be:
[image]

Is this possible and how would i implement this i read about using the .plist but i had no success.

Comment: Oh please don't tell me you are the one asking this question as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11912401/change-uidocumentinteractioncontroller-icons

Comment: Appears he is. Identical screenshot, same name, same question.

Comment: Hi yes that is mine but it wont let me add a comment on that account because of a third party cookie problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UTI` property of `UIDocumentInteractionController` gives you the *uniform type identifier* for a file, see [Uniform Type Identifier Concepts](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/understand_utis_conc/understand_utis_conc.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001319-CH202-CHDHIJDE). For example, "public.tiff" for TIFF files, "public.jpeg" for JPEG files and "com.apple.quicktime-movie" for QuickTime Movies.

Uniform type identifiers are declared in a *conformance hierarchy*. TIFF and JPEG files are both images, and in the UTI concept this is expressed by the fact that both "public.tiff" and "public.jpeg" *conform to* "public.image".

This being said, you could do the following to display your own icon for all image file types.

- Add that icon to your app resources, for example "myimageicon.png".
- To choose an icon for a file, check if the UTI of that file conforms to "public.image" and use your icon in that case. Otherwise use a default icon.

  ```
  // Assuming that self.docInteractionController is already set up ...
  if (UTTypeConformsTo((CFStringRef)self.docInteractionController.UTI, kUTTypeImage)) {
      cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myimageicon.png"];
  } else {
      cell.imageView.image = docInteractionController.icons.lastObject;
  }
  ```

You have to import `<MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>` and add the `MobileCoreServices.framework` to make this compile.

Comment: Better to make __bridge cast of CFStringRef (iOS7)